# Specify timeout in wsclient

Tags: timeout, griffon, ws-client

What is the proper way for specifying the timeout in wsclient.

I tried in my griffon controller this :

```
withWs([wsdl: model.wsdl, timeout:1800000])
```

but it does not seem to work.

Any hints?

Problem solved by doing this :

```
withWs(wsdl: model.wsdl){
    setConnnectionTime(1800000)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter much but try removing the square brackets from the call, like this

```
withWs(wsdl: model.wsdl, timeout:1800000) { ... }
```

According to line 101 of WsclientConnector the timeout parameter should be honored by the WS client

```
if(params.containsKey('timeout')) client.setConnectionTimeout(params.remove('timeout'))
```

Comment: Sorry the late answser ! I finally found a way to solve my problem thanks to your pointer.